# Python PyQt Send Data Between Forms

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two forms built with Qt Designer. The two forms  utilize the uic.loadUiType process described [here](https://www.pythonforengineers.com/your-first-gui-app-with-python-and-pyqt/). I have uploaded the UI forms to [this location](https://github.com/dkuzdas/PYqt-SendDataBetweenClasses/find/master) To import the forms. The Main windows has three push buttons. When each button is pushed – attempting to pass which button was passed to the Number Pad Form – trying to use signals and slots but not working.

When the NumPad form opens I need it to populate with Field1, 2, or 3 so that I can pass the contents of txtDatToPass back to the Main Window Form. Not sure why the signals and not getting through. Any thoughts or guidance would be helpful
Thanks

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic


qtCreatorFile = "MainWinForm.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

qtCreatorFileKeyPad = "NumPadForm.ui"
Ui_KeyPad, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFileKeyPad )


class PunchWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    signalPassDataToMainForm = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str,str)
    def __init__(self):
        super(PunchWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_KeyPad()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.move(850, 200) #Center Screen

  #NumberPad
        self.ui.btnOne.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(1))
        self.ui.btnTwo.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(2))
        self.ui.btnThree.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(3))
        self.ui.btnFour.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(4))
        self.ui.btnFive.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(5))
        self.ui.btnSix.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(6))
        self.ui.btnSeven.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(7))
        self.ui.btnEight.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(8))
        self.ui.btnNine.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(9))
        self.ui.btnZero.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad(0))
        self.ui.btnDot.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad("."))
        self.ui.btnBackSpace.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad("BS"))
        self.ui.btnClear.clicked.connect(lambda: self.numberPad("Clear"))
        self.ui.btnEnter.clicked.connect(self.Enter)
##
    def numberPad(self, n):
        print(n)
        strField = self.ui.txtDataField.toPlainText()
        if(strField == "Field1") or (strField == "Field2") or (strField == "Field3"):
            strValue = self.ui.txtDataToPass.toPlainText()
            strN = str(n)
            if(strN == "BS"):
                strTrim = strValue[:-1]
                self.ui.txtDataToPass.setText(strTrim)
            elif(strN == "Clear"):
                self.ui.txtDataToPass.setText("")
            else:        
                strValue = strValue + strN 
                self.ui.txtDataToPass.setText(strValue)

    def Enter(self):
        strFieldNo = self.ui.txtDataField.toPlainText()
        strSendData = self.ui.txtDataToPass.toPlainText()
        print("Trying to send contents of txtDataToPass back to MainWindow Form -- Data Field:  " + strFieldNo +  "      Data: "  + strSendData)
        self.signalPassDataToMainForm.emit(strFieldNo, strSendData)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    signalPassData = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str) # used to send Field1, 2 , or 3 to Punch Window

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()        
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.move(450, 200) #Center Screen

        self.ui.btnField1.clicked.connect(self.Field1)
        self.ui.btnField2.clicked.connect(self.Field2)
        self.ui.btnField3.clicked.connect(self.Field3)

        #Should recieve signals back from PunchWindow
        self.Punch = PunchWindow()
        self.Punch.signalPassDataToMainForm.connect(self.Update)

    def Update(self, strField, strData):
        self.ui.txtData1.setText(strData)

    def Field1(self):
        strField = "Field1"
        print(strField)
        self.ui.SW = PunchWindow()
        self.ui.SW.show()
        self.signalPassData.emit(strField)

    def Field2(self):
        strField = "Field2"
        print(strField)
        self.ui.SW = PunchWindow()
        self.ui.SW.show()
        self.signalPassData.emit(strField)

    def Field3(self):
        strField = "Field3"
        print(strField)
        self.ui.SW = PunchWindow()
        self.ui.SW.show()
        self.signalPassData.emit(strField)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to design the classes, in the case of PunchWindow you must have a method to update the txtDataField and have a signal that sends the data to MainWindow. On the other hand in MainWindow every time you press on the buttons you must update the txtDataField using the method that was mentioned initially, then it is in the slot connected to signalPassDataToMainForm you must distinguish the appropriate field.

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

qtCreatorFile = "MainWinForm.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

qtCreatorFileKeyPad = "NumPadForm.ui"
Ui_KeyPad, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFileKeyPad )

class PunchWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_KeyPad):
    signalPassDataToMainForm = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PunchWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.move(850, 200) #Center Screen
        buttons = (self.btnOne, self.btnTwo, self.btnThree, self.btnFour,
            self.btnFive, self.btnSix, self.btnSeven, self.btnEight,
            self.btnNine, self.btnZero, self.btnDot, self.btnBackSpace,
            self.btnClear)
        vals = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, ".", "BS", "Clear")
        for button, val in zip(buttons, vals):
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.numberPad, val))
        self.btnEnter.clicked.connect(self.enter)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def setCurrentField(self, text):
        self.txtDataField.setPlainText(text)

    def numberPad(self, n):
        strField = self.txtDataField.toPlainText()
        if strField in ("Field1", "Field2", "Field3"):
            strValue = self.txtDataToPass.toPlainText()
            strN = str(n)
            if strN == "BS":
                self.txtDataToPass.setPlainText(strValue[:-1])
            elif strN == "Clear":
                self.txtDataToPass.clear()
            else:        
                strValue += strN 
                self.txtDataToPass.setPlainText(strValue)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def enter(self):
        strFieldNo = self.txtDataField.toPlainText()
        strSendData = self.txtDataToPass.toPlainText()
        self.signalPassDataToMainForm.emit(strFieldNo, strSendData)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.move(450, 200) #Center Screen
        buttons = (self.btnField1, self.btnField2, self.btnField3)
        fields = ("Field1", "Field2", "Field3")
        for button, field in zip(buttons, fields):
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.updatePunch, field))
        self.punch = PunchWindow()
        self.punch.signalPassDataToMainForm.connect(self.updateField)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def updateField(self, strField, strData):
        if strField == "Field1":
            self.txtData1.setText(strData)
        elif strField == "Field2":
            self.txtData2.setText(strData)
        elif strField == "Field3":
            self.txtData3.setText(strData)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def updatePunch(self, field):
        self.punch.setCurrentField(field)
        self.punch.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @QtCore.pyqtSlot()

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc --  Provided solutions works!! You answered the question and also provided much needed guidance on my code style. If i may another question -- could you provide a short reply on when or when not to use @QtCore.pyqtSlot() . Thanks

Comment: @dkuzdas you can actually use it for any method of widgets (in general of any class that inherits from QObject) but it is used for methods that connect to signals. On the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. read http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html